# The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout - Azure blob copying timeout issue

Tags: azure, blob

I am getting timeout issue , halfway when i'm trying to copy one blob to another.  I am just copying 670 MB of data . But when it reaches 110 MB of blob copying im getting this error .
Any solution here would be greatly helpful

```cs
private async Task CopyHalfFolderBlobAsync(ICloudBlob srcBlob,ICloudBlob destBlob)
    {             
        try
        {
            await destBlob.StartCopyFromBlobAsync(new Uri(srcBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you copying blobs? Please share your code.

Comment: Updated my question with the Code . Should i use any RetryPolicy . Kindly advice

Comment: Are you getting timeout from storage service? Are you copying blobs through a web application?

Comment: Im copying using a WPF application. Im getting error from the blob client.

Comment: Used the Synchronous method StartCopyFromBlob and it solved the issue though the UI was blocked till the entire copy operation was finished